# Can I deploy an .ashx file on Linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, dll, ashx

I have a .ashx file that call a .dll file and I want to deploy this on my Apache server, so I can call it with a HTTP POST request and get the response I want.

Those are the two only files I have...

I tried to deploy it locally with IIS on my Windows by putting my files directly in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ directory, and it worked fine.

I also saw that it is possible to deploy an ASP.NET Core application on an Apache server. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-7.0)
So I tried to create a project with Visual Studio and put my files in the wwwroot directory of the project, but I can't call my .ashx file.

I precise that I have no knowledge about ASP.NET or C#.

So, what I want to know is : do I really need to put my files in an ASP.NET Core application to deploy it on Apache ?
If yes, how to call my .ashx within the project ?
And if not, is there any other way to deploy my files on Apache ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core does not use .ashx  AFAIK. .ashx is file from legacy ASP.NET versions.

Comment: So in short - no, you need to rewrite your app using modern technologies (though maybe something is possible with a lot of effort).

Comment: @GuruStron So if I can't modify the existing code of my files, it is impossible to deploy the application on an Apache server ?

Comment: I would say yes

Comment: Your ultimate goal is to invoke some method in a DLL, right? So why are you so focused on the .ashx? Instead, create an ASP.NET Core app that references the DLL, and have an endpoint (controller action or minimal API for example) that is responsible for invoking the DLL.

Comment: @mason Since I have no knowledge about C# and ASP.NET, it would have been better if I use the files that I already have. But yes, if it's the only way to solve the problem I will search how to invoke the method of the DLL without the .ashx. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It's not the *only* way. Mono is an alternative .NET implementation that runs on Linux, and can run ASP.NET apps, presumably including .ashx files. It's just that resources and knowledge on it are scarce compared to Microsoft's official .NET implementations. And there's really no point in using Mono now, since ASP.NET Core runs on Linux and is far better documented/supported and unified with how .NET runs on Windows.

Comment: Here is the next part of my problem and the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128401/error-using-asp-net-application-with-mono